# wrap text xlsxwriter columns pd dataframe python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I have an xlsx file that I'm trying to write in and for some reason can't seem to be able to do the formatting of text to wrap in the cell:

I've tried like bellow (have taken out lines that I don't think are important), but text won't wrap, if i do other conditional_formating it works, this text wrap it doesn't thou:

```
the df is defined...

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f"{xlsx_file}", engine='xlsxwriter')

df['Statistics'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Statistics', index=False)
...
text_wrap = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})
...
for sheet in all_sheets:
        worksheet = writer.sheets[f"{sheet}"]
        worksheet.set_column(1, 6, 25)
        if sheet == "Statistics":
            worksheet.conditional_format(f'A1:A16', {'type': 'cell',
                                                     'criteria': '!=',
                                                     'value': '0',
                                                     'format': text_wrap})

writer.save()
```

The workbook and the other lines that I don't think are relevant I've taken them out from the code above for simplicity.
The idea is that there is a workbook with multiple sheets and would like to apply the conditional formatting only to 1 column (first) from a specific sheet.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've tried like below (...), but text won't wrap, if i do other conditional_formating it works, this text wrap it doesn't

Excel doesn't support text wrap, or other alignment properites, in conditional formats so the XlsxWriter formatting is just being ignored (by Excel).

Comment: Hmm, There is no other way of having it written human readable? The idea is that some of the cells have 60 characters. And others just few and don’t know how to make it more readable. I was thinking about doing colum width bigger but like this all would go to much to the right..